# Use Select2 and X-Editable together with latest versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, x-editable

All the examples online that I see show how to use X-Editable with Select2 library are using older versions of select2.

**X-Editable** -  http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/ with
**Select2** - https://select2.github.io/ for weeks now without much luck.

Has anyone got these 2 libraries recently with versions released in the past year even to work together?

Comment: See my comment below on Kevin Brown.  Hoping we as a community can find someone to help get this project updated again to support Select2.  There are many people that are wanting this right now!

Answer (score 6):

I also run into this problem recently and come up a cheat. It uses the standard 'select' and turn it into a select2 on show:

```js
$('#stages').editable({
  source: [ {value: 1, text:'ahaa'}, {value: 2, text: 'ohooo'} ]
}).on('shown', function(e, editable){
  editable.input.$input.select2({
    width: 250,
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
  });
  editable.input.$input.select2('val', editable.input.$input.val());
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"
   id="stages"
   data-type="select"
   data-placement="right"
   class="editable editable-click"
   data-value="1"
   data-title="Select something"></a>
```

Comment: sneaky. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Select2 4.0.0 is not compatible with X-Editable, and there doesn't appear to be any support coming in the future.

Back in January [I created a ticket about it](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/706), and there has not been any response from the maintainers. The X-Editable project is currently frozen and looking for maintainers.

Comment: I actually just posted an article on my Web Dev blog here http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/community-looking-for-expert-javascript-developer-to-update-x-editable-jquery-library-project/ about the issue of trying to find someone to take over the project.  It's a long shot but it's such a great library, I feel I have to at least try and find someone instead of just giving up hope on it.  If enough people spread the word, perhaps just the right person will see it and be able to help with the project!  It's not completely impossible!

Comment: When viewing the recent issues in X-Editable I also notice that majority of the recent ones are related to Select2 support issues so it would be really nice to find someone able to update this part at the least!  Feel free to spread the word if you'd like to contribute to helping up find that somebody or group  of somebody's even!  thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten the latest version of Select2 (4.0.3) to work with x-editable.

Use this fork of x-editable (not by me, by one of the Select2 authors)
https://github.com/select2/x-editable

And then for whichever distribution you choose in the js file find this line:

```
tpl:'<input type="hidden">',
```

and change to this:

```
tpl:'<select multiple></select>',
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the recent versions are OK now, but X-Editable's DOCs states that you need to import select2's js and css, here's my working example:

```
<link href="css/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/select2/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.editable_example').editable({
        source: [
            {id: 1, text: 'Test1'},
            {id: 2, text: 'Test2'},
            {id: 3, text: 'Test3'}
        ]
    });
</script>

<body>
    <!-- normal code and than the x editable input -->
    <a href="#" data-name="example" data-type="select2" 
        class="editable_example" data-pk="5" data-url="ajax/update_row.php"
        data-title="Select one item" data-value="5">
        John Example
    </a>
</body>
```

I strongly recommend taking a few minutes to [read the DOCs](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select2) and learn a few observations like the need to import select2's js and css and things like that.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#number').editable({
  source: [ 
    {value: 1, text:'One'}, 
    {value: 2, text: 'Two'} 
  ],
  select2: {
    placeholder: 'Select',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/x-editable@1.5.1/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/x-editable@1.5.1/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css">
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@3.5.1/select2.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@3.5.1/select2.min.js"></script>

<a href="#"
   id="number"
   data-type="select2"
   data-placement="right"
   data-value="1"
   data-title="Select Number"></a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Having also hit this problem on a recent project I've created a custom extension specifically for select2 version 4.0.2 that works with x-editable. I've also added the ability to have unique dropdown data per row if required.

Blog post and download available at [www.fifthmorrison.com](http://www.fifthmorrison.com/?p=239)

Agreed on the excellence of this plugin and if anyone does have time to take over it would definitely be appreciated here.

Hope that helps in the meantime!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Link only responses are discouraged - could you edit your post to add a minimal example?

Comment: the link is not accessible

Comment: Yes, sorry! This was sadly lost and I'm not currently using a public blog. If I do re-published I will add here again.